# uploading app with Upload Key on Google Play Store (Concept)

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have uploaded my Signed APK to Google Play.

I did following Steps

1.Generated a KeyStore and key using this [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

2.Step 1 gaves me Signed APK

3.I enrolled my app on Google Play Singing Program

4.My APK Successfully uploaded.

My confusion is,

Where is upload key? where is my Signing key? is my application uploaded using upload key or my signing key? Im lit bit confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have accepted Google Play Singing Program without reading no agreement no marketing materials about it. This is bad.

The key you've created and signed the app - was used as "upload key". If you already had downloaded some key into Signing Program - your app will be resigned by that key and will be published.

If you didn't downloaded any key yet - your app publish is delayed until you download some key into Signing Program, and the key you would download will be used to resign your app.